# psycopg2 postgres database syntax error near value

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert info from a pandas DataFrame into a database table by using a function that I wrote:

```
def insert(table_name="", name="", genere="", year=1, impd_rating=float(1)):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='database1' user='postgres' password='postgres333' host='localhost' port=5433 ")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES %s,%s,%s,%s"  % (table_name, name, genere, year, impd_rating))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

When I try to use this function like this:

```
b=0
for row in DF['id']:
    insert(impd_rating=float(DF['idbm_rating'][b]), 
           year=int(DF['year'][b]), 
           name=str(DF['name'][b]), 
           genere=str(DF['genere'][b]),
           table_name='test_movies')
    b = b+1
```

I get the following syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS D:\tito\scripts\database training> python .\postgres_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\postgres_script.py", line 56, in <module>insert (impd_rating=float(DF['idbm_rating'][b]),year=int(DF['year'][b]),name=str(DF['name'][b]),genere=str(DF['genere'][b]),table_name='test_movies')
File ".\postgres_script.py", line 15, in insert
cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES %s,%s,%s,%s"  % (table_name ,name ,genere , year,impd_rating))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "Avatar"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO test_movies VALUES Avatar,action,2009,7.9
```

I also tried to change the str replacement method from `%s` to `.format()`
but I had the same error.

Comment: Never ever use string formatting on SQL queries. It leads to SQL injections.

Comment: thank you i saw that when i was reading this article [link](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters)

Answer (score 6):

The error message is explicit, this SQL command is wrong at `Avatar`: `INSERT INTO test_movies VALUES Avatar,action,2009,7.9`. Simply because values must be enclosed in parenthesis, and character strings must be quoted, so the correct SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO test_movies VALUES ('Avatar','action',2009,7.9)
```

But building a full SQL command by concatenating parameters is bad practice (*), only the table name should be directly inserted into the command because is is not a SQL parameter. The correct way is to use a parameterized query:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?,?,?,?)"  % (table_name,) ,(name ,genere , year,impd_rating)))
```

---

(*) It was the cause of numerous *SQL injection* flaws because if one of the parameter contains a semicolumn (`;`) what comes after could be interpreted as a new command

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has a DataFrame method for this, [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
# Only needs to be executed once.
conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='database1' user='postgres' password='postgres333' host='localhost' port=5433 ")


df.to_sql('test_movies', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

This should hopefully get you going in the right direction.

Comment: i tried that code   

    DF.to_sql('test_movies', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

but it gives me that error 

   pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Comment: If sqlalchemy is not installed, I believe you can only use sqlite.

Comment: ok i installed sqlalchemy so i need to import it and use the code up ahead ??

Comment: You need to create an engine: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html.  Then create a connection: `conn = engine.connect()`.  Pass this connection to the `.to_sql` method above.

Answer (score 2):

In your original query

`INSERT INTO %s VALUES %s,%s,%s,%s`

there is a sql problem: you need braces around the values, i.e. it should be `VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)`. On top of that the table name cannot be merged as a parameter, or it would be escaped as a string, which is not what you want.

You can use the [psycopg 2.7 sql module](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) to merge the table name to the query, with placeholders for the values:

```
from psycopg2 import sql

query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)").format(
    sql.Identifier('test_movies'))

cur.execute(query, ('Avatar','action',2009,7.9))
```

This will make secure both merging the table name and the arguments to the query.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello mohamed mahrous,**

First install psycopg2 package for the access access PostgreSQL database.

Try this below code,

```
import psycopg2
conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='database1' user='postgres' password='postgres333' host='localhost' port=5433 ")
cur=conn.cursor()

def insert(table_name,name,genere,year,impd_rating): 
    query = "INSERT INTO "+table_name+"(name,genere,year,impd_rating) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    try:
        print query
        cur.execute(query,(name,genere,year,impd_rating))
    except Exception, e:
        print "Not execute..."
    conn.commit()

b=0
for row in DF['id']:
    insert (impd_rating=float(DF['idbm_rating'][b]),year=int(DF['year'][b]),name=str(DF['name'][b]),genere=str(DF['genere'][b]),table_name='test_movies')
    b= b+1

conn.close()
```

**Example,**

```
import psycopg2
conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='database1' user='postgres' password='postgres333' host='localhost' port=5433 ")
cur=conn.cursor()

def insert(table_name,name,genere,year,impd_rating): 
    query = "INSERT INTO "+table_name+"(name,genere,year,impd_rating) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    try:
        print query
        cur.execute(query,(name,genere,year,impd_rating))
    except Exception, e:
        print "Not execute"
    conn.commit()

b=0
for row in DF['id']:
    insert (impd_rating="7.0",year="2017",name="Er Ceo Vora Mayur",genere="etc",table_name="test_movies")
    b= b+1

conn.close()
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comment please.

Comment: now it gives me this error 'psycopg2.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

 '

Comment: Now Updated answer so try this.. this answer is successful run for me...

Comment: sorry man didn't worked for me but anyway i overwhelmed the problem with using sqlalchemy and to_sql method from pandas thanks for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: exception psycopg2.InternalError

Exception raised when the database encounters an internal error, e.g. the cursor is not valid anymore, the transaction is out of sync, etc. It is a subclass of DatabaseError.


http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html

Comment: May above link helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for my issue by using sqlalchemy and pandas to_sql method
thanks for help everyone

```
from sqlalchemy import *
import pandas as pd
def connect(user, password, db, host='localhost', port=5433):

    '''Returns a connection and a metadata object'''

    # We connect with the help of the PostgreSQL URL

    # postgresql://federer:grandestslam@localhost:5432/tennis

    url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'

    url = url.format(user, password, host, port, db)

    # The return value of create_engine() is our connection object

    con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')

    # We then bind the connection to MetaData()

    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=con, reflect=True)

    return con, meta

con, meta = connect('postgres','postgres333','database1')
movies= Table('test',meta,
Column('id',Integer,primary_key=True),
Column('name',String),
Column('genere',String),
Column('year',Integer),
Column('idbm_rating',REAL))
meta.create_all(con)

DF=pd.read_csv('new_movies.txt',sep='       ',engine='python')
DF.columns=('id','name' ,'genere' ,'year' ,'idbm_rating' )
DF.to_sql('movies', con=con, if_exists='append', index=False)
```